# Data visualization libraries in maps

Tags: data-visualization, maps

I am working on a web app to visualize climate data. I am using Leaflet as my map engine, and although I have player around with some plugins, I didn't find any that could provide the kind of visualization I am looking for.

This could be an example of the kind of result I want to achieve:

[image]

I have data in geojson point format, although transformations are possible.
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Your question is rather vague. Please try add more details about the plugin you are looking for. What is distinctive for you in the picture you share? Is it the color scheme that is particular? The blurry edges towards blue and the shard edges towards black?

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for your answers :) I can and should provide more context indeed. The distinctive feature I am looking for is the gradient interpolation between different data points, and detailed controls upon the heatmap itself. I have tested several heatmap plugins (as the one you shared). I'd need to be able to set a specific point size that is independent on the zoom level, and configurable color scheme.

Still, I am not sure a heatmap is what I am looking for. I was considering writing some shader that draws a 2D gradient within the polygon that encompasses the points.

Comment: "Blurry edges towards blue and the shard edges towards black" is also a very nice feature, I'd say this falls into the interpolation and color handling territory.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  Please update your question to include details about that distinctive feature - because as it is currently written, you essentially ask "I want something that looks great - just as this image it beautiful, eh?"

Answer (score 1):

From the little information provided, I guess that what you are looking for is a plugin to do [heat map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) visualization.

A simple heat map plugin for Leaflet is [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat).